# Finding cycles in graph results in empty array

Tags: python, networking, graph, theory

I am trying to find all cycles in a directed graph, I am using networks library for this. The program executes normally and results an empty array.
I am not sure how the networks library works but my use case graphs may have discontinuities in them.

I have attached the code below

```
import networkx as nx


G.add_nodes_from(['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18'])
G.add_edges_from([('1', '2'), ('1', '8'), ('1', '9'), ('1', '10'), ('1', '11'), ('1', '14'), ('1', '15'), ('1', '18'), ('2', '3'), ('2', '8'), ('2', '18'), ('3', '4'), ('3', '7'), ('3', '17'), ('4', '5'), ('4', '6'), ('4', '7'), ('4', '12'), ('4', '13'), ('4', '16'), ('4', '17'), ('5', '6'), ('5', '10'), ('5', '12'), ('6', '7'), ('6', '9'), ('7', '8'), ('8', '9'), ('9', '10'), ('10', '11'), ('11', '12'), ('11', '14'), ('12', '13'), ('13', '14'), ('13', '16'), ('14', '15'), ('15', '16'), ('15', '18'), ('16', '17'), ('17', '18')])

print(list(nx.simple_cycles(G)))
```

There are supposed to be a few cycles in my example.

Please let me know what am I doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

print(list(nx.find_cycle(G, source=list of nodes)))

Comment: I tried that , it gives me the first cycle found. I want all possible cycles in graph

Comment: Duplicate your graph, while cycle found: store it somewhere, remove it from graph, keep on searching.